# Dynamically updates CSS styles based on condition in Angular

Tags: css, angular, dropdown

My team implemented a multi-select dropdown using ng-multiselect-dropdown, and I've encountered a bug where the body div will scroll with the height of your dropdown options when the dropdown is triggered, regardless of the height of the dropdown box itself.

This issue can be seen here: [[example]](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fdginy) & has also been submitted to the ng-multiselect-dropdown issue board [[x]](https://github.com/NileshPatel17/ng-multiselect-dropdown/issues/248), but no updates have been made.

A quick fix for this issue is to set `body {overflow: hidden}`, however I do still need the overflow function to display all the data on my page.

Is there a way that I can remove the overflow from the body, if the dropdown has been triggered/is active?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the issue workaround on github, you need to set the `overflow-y: hidden` only on the `.dropdown-list` class. Adding the snippet below to the styles.css seems to solve the problem.

```
.dropdown-list {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

You can check the live example [in this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-j9je4v?file=src/styles.css)